# Magento 2: How to get categories URLs?

Tags: magento2, php, category

I use the following PHP code to get all categories and subcategories, the code is work, the only issue is that code doesn't have the URL. Is there any way to get/add URLs too?

```
function categoryLoop($id, $is_sub = false){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);
    if($categories->hasChildren()){
    echo '<ul' . (($is_sub) ? ' class="category_children"' : '') . '>';
        $subcategories = explode(',', $categories->getChildren());
        foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
            $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
            echo '<li>';
            echo $subcategory->getName();
            echo "</li>";
            if($subcategory->hasChildren()){ categoryLoop($category, true); }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
categoryLoop(2);  // enter your category id here
```

I created a CMS page for the contact page.

Comment: Try with $subcategory->getUrl()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some changes in your code as given below.

1 . Get category url.

```
...
...
echo '<li><a href="'.$subcategory->getUrl().'">';
echo $subcategory->getName();
echo "</a></li>";
...
...
```

2 . Add an unique class in every **ul** tag.

```
...
...
$categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);
if($categories->hasChildren()){
echo '<ul' . (($is_sub) ? ' class="category_children category-'.$categories->getId().'"' : '') . '>';
...
...
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: is okay I think is all that we can do with that code? right?

Comment: Yes this will add an unique class in every ul and category url in every category. If my answer worked , you can upvote and accept my answer so It can help others also.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I really appreciate this

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this code :

```
foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
  $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<a href='.$subcategory->getUrl().'>';
  echo $subcategory->getName();
  echo "</a>";
  echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: thank you but how I can add an a href element there to contain Name and Url?

Comment: I update my answer, please check.

Comment: If answer help you please accept it as solution, so it will help other in community as well.

Comment: please tell me something, can we separate the first ul and the second? I mean to add a class to the first and to the second? I

Comment: If you have new question then ask by clicking on Ask question.

Comment: is not a new question, is related with that code, how we can separate that ul, how we can add new classe for first and second ul element?

Comment: What do you mean by second UL?

Comment: here is a loop: if($subcategory->hasChildren()){ categoryLoop($category, true); }, I want to have different classes here in this loop

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $subcategory->getUrl();
```

Checkout this one.

Comment: Also add explanation of what your code do. It will make your answer more useful